# How to get use count from Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, kernel-module

I have a problem with use count of kernel module being developed.I'd like to print it for debugging purpose. How can I obtain it from the module code?

Kernel version in question - Linux 2.6.32

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`module_refcount()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.34.1/include/linux/module.h#L456) will give you the use count of the module passed.

Comment: What argument should I provide to get use count of my module? P.S. I'll try THIS_MODULE.

Answer (score 0):

/sbin/lsmod

The third column will be the number of usages.